# How to automate Google Wallet order export data?

Tags: python, ruby, android-pay

I am working to automate retrieving the Order data from the Google Wallet Merchant Center. This data is on the Orders screen and the export is through a button right above the data.

Google has said this data is not available to export to a Google Cloud bucket like payments are and this data is not available through a Google API.

I'm wondering if anyone has been successful in automating retrieval of this data using an unofficial method such as scraping the site or a separate gem or library? I have done tons of searching and have not seen any solutions.

Comment: Just a thought - do you implement a [`postback url`](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback) where Google sends order data?

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: @AlexBlack yes, I ended up writing a scraping utility using the Mechanize gem.

Answer (score 0):

analyticsPierce,

I've asked the same question and have not received any answers.

Here was my question, maybe we can work out a solution somehow.  I've just about given up.

"HttpWebRequest with Username/Password"  on StackOverflow.

Trey